# WkHtmlToPdf-DotNet automatically moves div to a new line?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor-server-side, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to save a table into a PDF on my Blazor project.

Blazor can successfully render the correct formation of the table.

However, it seems that WkHtmlToPdf automatically moved div to a new line when I tried to generate a PDF file.

[WkHtmlToPdf Generated Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKZAM.png)

I want it to be displayed as a table.

[Blazor Rendered Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9XmI.png)

I tried Bootstrap col row but no luck.

Or is my coding wrong? I can post it on CodePen if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently WkHtmlToPdf does not support multiple columns. 
Use table or other libraries if you want to generate PDFs.